# Create Backdrop on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to create functionality exactly as displayed in my **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/hBB97/1/)**, Basically to hover over a div and then to have a backdrop beneath that div along with a slide down panel also above the backdrop. the only issue is that the functionality is very buggy and barely works in internet explorer.

Here is the JS:

```
function darken(panelOpen){
        if(panelOpen){
            if(jQuery('#menu-backdrop').length){
                jQuery("#menu-backdrop").stop().fadeIn(300);
            }else{
                jQuery(document.body).stop().append(jQuery('<div id="menu-backdrop" class="modal-backdrop"></div>').css('opacity',0.7).hide().fadeIn(300));
            }
        }else{
            jQuery(".modal-backdrop").stop().fadeOut(300);
        }
    } //Backdrop

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {    

    var bioId;

    jQuery('.personnel').mouseover(function () {

        jQuery(this).css('z-index','1050');

        darken(true);

        bioId = '#personnel-bio-'+this.id.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');
        var bio = '#personnel-bio-'+this.id.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');
        if(jQuery(bio).is(':visible')){
        }else{
            jQuery(bio).slideDown(300);
        }
    }); //dropdown function

    jQuery(".wrap").mouseleave(function () {
        darken(false);

        if(jQuery(bioId).is(':visible')){
            jQuery(bioId).slideUp(300);
        }else{
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('.personnel').css('z-index','0');
        }, 300);
    }); // slide up function
});
```

and the CSS:

```
.personnel {
        position:relative;
}

.personnel-bio {
    display:none;
    padding:1.2em;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1050;
  margin-bottom:15px;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

And then Finally the HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div id="personnel-1" class="pull-left personnel">
                        <div class="personnel-inner">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/330x290"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail-title">
                                <h4>LAbel</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
 <div id="personnel-bio-1" class="personnel-bio">
                    <h5><strong>Pieter Strydom</strong></h5>

                    <p>loerm ipsum.</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

I am not quiet Sure what I am doing incorrectly. So Any Help at all will be Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tidied up the code a bit, removed unnecessary calls to `z-index` and `stop`
The modal-backdrop is in the DOM from the beginning now which also helps to speed things up.  The initial CSS is set on that with `opacity:0.7;` and `display:none;`
Should work a lot more fluid now.

http://jsfiddle.net/hBB97/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-backdrop" class="modal-backdrop"></div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="personnel-1" class="pull-left personnel">
        <div class="personnel-inner">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/330x290" />
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail-title">
                 <h4>Label</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="personnel-bio-1" class="personnel-bio">
         <h5><strong>Pieter Strydom</strong></h5>
        <p>loerm ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function darken(panelOpen, personnelContainer) {
    if (panelOpen) {
        personnelContainer.css('z-index', '1050');
        jQuery(".modal-backdrop").fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        jQuery(".modal-backdrop").fadeOut(300);
        personnelContainer.css('z-index', '0');
    }
} //Backdrop

jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {

    var bioId;

    jQuery('.personnel').mouseover(function () {

        darken(true, $(this));

        bioId = '#personnel-bio-' + this.id.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        var bio = '#personnel-bio-' + this.id.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        if (jQuery(bio).is(':visible')) {} else {
            jQuery(bio).slideDown(300);
        }
    }); //dropdown function

    jQuery(".personnel").mouseleave(function () {
        darken(false, $(this));

        if (jQuery(bioId).is(':visible')) {
            jQuery(bioId).slideUp(300);
        }
    }); // slide up function
});
```

CSS:

```
.personnel {
    position:relative;
}
.personnel-bio {
    display:none;
    padding:1.2em;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1050;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background:#FFF;
}
.modal-backdrop {
    display:none;
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

Comment: It works better, but there's is one issue. I have multiple images such as that and I only ever want one of them to be above the backdrop based on hover.

Comment: Strange seems fine/ok on both of those on my machine!  Good luck with finding a solution. P.s. see you're in Knysna! In Plett myself!